How to efficiently match different versions of grouped elements?
I'm trying to remap primary keys between versioned data and code releases with as small a diff as possible.
I have a list of elements, e.g. [a,b,c,...,j], and some deterministic process that assigns these elements to groups, e.g. g0_0={a,b,c}, g0_1={d,e,f,g,h}, g0_2={i}, and g0_3={j}.
Later, I add elements to the list, e.g. [k,l], and I improve my process, e.g. here my groups are g1_0={a,b}, g1_1={c,d}, g1_2={e,f,g,h,i,k}, g1_3={j,l}.
How can I efficiently obtain a mapping from old groups to new groups that minimises the differences between the mapped sets?
In this example we would see:
g0_0 |-> g1_0: diff=1
none |-> g1_1: diff=2 [i.e. new primary key]
g0_1 |-> g1_2: diff=3
g0_3 |-> g1_3: diff=1
total_diff = 7

I could assemble this as a mixed integer optimisation problem with a bipartite graph:
g0_0   g0_1   g0_2   g0_3
  |  \  |   \  |      |       
g1_0   g1_1   g1_2   g1-3  

where edges have discrete values [0,1], and I minimise the total difference.
However, in this application, my number of groups is much larger. I expect my adjacency matrix of size count(g0_*) times count(g1_*) will be too large to make this approach tractible.
The problem setup is many-to-many, but as I only have one Vn set of keys I want a one-to-one mapping to the Vn+1 groups, adding the differences from the isolates.
So I want to match on the maximum union between versions, in order of descending size.

Do you not want a many-to-one mapping?

This looks to me like a minimim flow problem.  Theere are many algorithms that can be used, but the best performance you will get  is with mixed integer linear programming.  You mention tractability, by which I assume you mean performance.  Have you measured your performance?  Do you know your performance requirement?

Thanks @ravenspoint! I think I want many-to-many - groups can divide between versions, as well as merge. (In the little example I gave it was many-to-one, but this doesn't need to be the case.) Yeah so I could solve this with a MIP, but if I had lots of groups in each version (say, ~mn) this adjacency matrix would get really big, making a very slow solve. Perhaps I could partition the groups somehow and solve many sub problems?

If that is so, then it is not a minimum flow problem.  Please provide an example where it is so.

Are the elements in a group guaranteed to be unique to the group ( i.e. no duplicates )?

"minimises the differences between the mapped sets"  What exactly does this mean?  Does it mean the sum of the edit distances between mapped groups ( not sets! )?  In your posted solution g0_1 is mapped to g1_1.  The edit distance between them is 3 ( delete d, add i and k ) so "g0_1,g0_2 |-> g1_1: diff=2" confuses me.  Please post an exact description of the objective function you are minimising.

No need to be snotty @ravenspoint! Sometimes life keeps us afk for a day. I've made some edits to the question, but in general, I think a simple greedy algorithm as you describe probably is right, and I've just been overcomplicating this. Thanks for your help!

I am sorry you found my questions "snotty".  They were intended to be helpful and to clarify things, so that you would get an answer that might be useful for you.

The OP wants "as small a diff as possible".
Unfortunately, there is no specification of how to calculate this 'diff' and the OP is not responding to comments.
I would assume that the 'diff' would be the edit distance between a pair of groups.  i.e. the number of insertions and deletions needed to move from one group to another.  e.g. g0_1={d,e,f,g,h} to g1_1={e,f,g,h,i,k} needs delete d, add i and k for edit distance 3.
But something is wrong, either in my assumption or in the posted question
g0_1,g0_2 |-> g1_1: diff=2

There is no way to sort this out since the OP seems to have abandoned the question.  So, I will forge ahead making the necessary assumptions as I go along.
Assumption 1: diff is calculated as the edit distance, and we need to minimize the sum of edit distances of mapped groups.
Assumption 2: Every group in the first version must be mapped to a group in the second version. i.e. many-to-one mapping with no omissions from version 1 groups
These assumptions make the algorithm to solve this very simple: the greedy algorithm where each group in version 1 is mapped to the version 2 group with the smallest edit distance.
This gives a different optimal solution from that posted by the OP.
0 -> 0, dist = 1
1 -> 1, dist = 3
2 -> 2, dist = 3
3 -> 2, dist = 1
Total 8

Here is the C++ code that implements this:
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

///////////////////// data structure ///////////////////

typedef std::string element_t;

typedef std::vector<element_t> group_t;

typedef std::vector<group_t> version_t;

// An edit distance between two groups
struct sEditDist
{
    int iv1;  // zero-based index to group in first version
    int iv2;  // zero-based index to group in second version
    int dist; // count of insertions and deletion needs to reach 2nd group from first

    void display();
};

typedef std::vector<sEditDist> vEdits_t;

//////////////////////// Globals //////////////////////////

// the versions
version_t v1, v2;

// the optimal connections
vEdits_t vConnections;

////////////////////// methods //////////////////////////////

/// @brief generate example from stackoverflow question
/// @return
/// https://stackoverflow.com/q/79258933/16582
void gen1()
{
    // g0_0={a,b,c}, g0_1={d,e,f,g,h}, g0_2={i}, and g0_3={j}.
    v1 = version_t{
        {"a", "b", "c"},
        {"d", "e", "f", "g", "h"},
        {"i"},
        {"j"}};

    // g1_0={a,b,c,d}, g1_1={e,f,g,h,i,k}, g1_2={j,l}
    v2 = version_t{
        {"a", "b", "c", "d"},
        {"e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "k"},
        {"j", "l"}};
}
/// @brief edit distance between two groups
/// @param g1
/// @param g2
/// @return
int editDistance(
    const group_t &g1,
    const group_t &g2)
{
    /* Do a linear search through a possible mapping between version 1 and 2 groups
    calculating the edit distance ( number of insertions and deletions reuired ) between them.

    This is the bottleneck.  It is blindingly fast for a few elements 
    O(N) where N is the number of elements ( element present in both versions counts for 2 )
    When there are more than ~100,000 elements this might drag a bit.

    TODO: This can be optimised by sorting the members of each group and doing a binary search

    */
    int dist = 0;
    for (auto &e : g1)
    {
        auto it = std::find(g2.begin(), g2.end(), e);
        if (it == g2.end())
            dist++; // element needs to be added to first group
    }
    for (auto &e : g2)
    {
        auto it = std::find(g1.begin(), g1.end(), e);
        if (it == g1.end())
            dist++; // element needs to be deleted from first group
    }
    return dist;
}

/// @brief connect v1 groups to v2 groups, mimimizing the total edit distance
void Connect()
{
    sEditDist ed;
    for (ed.iv1 = 0; ed.iv1 < v1.size(); ed.iv1++)
    {
        int bestv2 = 0;
        int bestDist = INT_MAX;
        for (ed.iv2 = 0; ed.iv2 < v2.size(); ed.iv2++)
        {
            // calculate edit distance
            ed.dist = editDistance(
                v1[ed.iv1],
                v2[ed.iv2]);
            ed.display();

            // keep the smallest edit distance
            if (ed.dist < bestDist)
            {
                bestDist = ed.dist;
                bestv2 = ed.iv2;
            }
        }
        // add connection with smallest edit distance from g1
        ed.iv2 = bestv2;
        ed.dist = bestDist;
        vConnections.push_back(ed);
    }
}
void ConnectDisplay()
{
    std::cout << "\nOptimal mapping between versions\n";
    for (auto &d : vConnections)
        d.display();
}

void sEditDist::display()
{
    std::cout << iv1 << " -> " << iv2 << ", dist = " << dist << "\n";
}

/////////////// Main //////////////////////

main()
{
    // generate problem
    gen1();

    // make connections
    Connect();

    // display result
    ConnectDisplay();
    return 0;
}

The complete VSCODE project for this application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79258933
